# wp_get_current_user() not recognised

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add the current user id from a Wordpress site to a table I have set up. All other values from inputs are going in fine, but I'm getting a php error when I try this code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "XXXXXX", "XXXXXX", "XXXXXX");

if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$latLng = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['latLng']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['title']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['type']);

$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$WP_id = $current_user->ID;

$sql = "INSERT INTO  `user_locations` (  `id` ,  `WP_id` , `latLng` ,      `type` ,  `title` ) VALUES ('', '$WP_id', '$latLng',  '$type',  '$title')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
header("Location: leaflet-test-page");
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

The error is:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /home/XXXXX/public_html/XXXXXX/insert.php on line 17`

Any help identifying the reason I am getting this error would be appreciated.

Comment: did you include the wp libraries? WP isn't built into php.

Comment: Well in another php file I have, I was able to echo WP user details using `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login;`
Doesn't work in this file though. Nothing special added to the other one.

Comment: as @MarcB you are trying to call a built-in wordpress function, but you're running it from `/home/XXXXX/public_html/XXXXXX/insert.php` which does not look like it's part of a wordpress theme. You should integrate your code to the current active wordpress theme in its' functions.php file. Also, wordpress already has an existing database connection - I suggest reading more about how to [integrate your code with wordpress database](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this worked. `include_once '../../../wp-blog-header.php';` I know its nasty, but does the trick for what I need it for.